# How do I separate custom template from the administration theme?

Tags: theming

I have made a custom template for the user_profile_form. I made a module and in the module I added the hook_theme function:

```
function myuser_theme() {
  $items = array();

  $items['user_profile_form'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'myuser'),
    'template' => 'user-account-form',
  );

  return $items;
}
```

This works as suspected but the theme is also applied in the administration theme. How can I have a custom template for the profile form and retain the original layout from the administration theme?

Answer (score 0):

You can sniff the user's role and/or permissions and then conditionally change the template.

You can test permissions with `user_access('view the administration theme')` and depending on the result, assign your custom template.